# Error handling in Bot Framework dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

How can I catch all exceptions in dialogs? Is there something like ASP.NET Exception Filter?
I want to send different messages to user depending on exception type.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You are right about the fact that you can use `ExceptionFilter`.

You just have to do the following:

**Create your ExceptionFilter** class, for example to force the tracking of the exception in Application Insights (or in your case handle specific exception types):

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace BotDemo.App_Start
{
    public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext ctx)
        {
            HandleError(ctx);
        }

        private static void HandleError(HttpActionExecutedContext ctx)
        {
            ctx.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(ctx.Exception.Message)
            };

            var client = new TelemetryClient();
            client.TrackException(ctx.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to **define your exception filter** in your `Application_Start()`:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
         ...
```

That's it.

In fact Bot Framework template is using ASP.Net, so you have all the normal features.

Comment: If that reply was helpful, please don't forget to accept it, thanks