# Bot framework dialogs error handling

Tags: c#, botframework

I need to handle errors withing bot framework dialogs, where I have `IDialogContext` to send a message or to call another dialog.
At the moment I have

```
try
{
    await Conversation.SendAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    HandleExceptions(e, activity);
}
```

in MessagesController, but at this level the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DefaultIfException` already sends error message back to user.
Where and how can intercept an error before `DefaultIfException`, handle it and propagate unhandled to DefaultIfException.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error handling in Bot Framework dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068972/error-handling-in-bot-framework-dialogs)

Answer (score -1):

You can use your exception Layer to capture bot exception. Below code will help you to guide to proceed further. I was using that and it was working fine.

```
try 
   {
      // your code
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      await BotException.GenerateBotException(message.From.Name, ex);
   }
```

After that you need to create a Exception class to capture log in your custom DB or send email notification with exception details.

```
using System;
using GPP.Bot.DataAccessLayer;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;

namespace Gpp.Bot.ExceptionHandling
{
    public class BotException
    {
        public static List<ErrorLogProperties> BOTErrorLog(string Environment, string exceptionStack, string exceptionSource, string fullException, string loggedInUser, string exceptionDateTime)
        {
            // this code to capture data in Cutome DB
            return DbHelper.ExecuteList<ErrorLogProperties>(
                new Command { ComandText = "Your Stored Procedure" },
                new Parameter<string, object>("Environment", Environment),
                new Parameter<string, object>("exceptionStack", exceptionStack),
                new Parameter<string, object>("exceptionSource", exceptionSource),
                new Parameter<string, object>("fullException", fullException),
                new Parameter<string, object>("loggedInUser", loggedInUser),
                new Parameter<string, object>("exceptionDateTime", exceptionDateTime)
                );

        }

        public static async Task GenerateBotException(string LLID, Exception ex)
        {
           BotExceptionNotification(LLID.Split('*')[1], ex.StackTrace, ex.Source, ex.Message,LLID.Split('*')[0], DateTime.Now.ToString());   
           BOTErrorLog(LLID.Split('*')[1], ex.StackTrace, ex.Source, ex.Message,LLID.Split('*')[0], DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        public static void BotExceptionNotification(string Environment, string exceptionStack, string exceptionSource,
            string fullException, string loggedInUser, string exceptionDateTime)
        {
          // Send email code goes here using above peramaeters in you html
        }

    }
}
```

Do let me know in case you required more help